# check if notification is scheduled or not

Tags: flutter, notifications

I am building a notification alert to notify user 30 minutes before the meeting time .
How can i check if the notification is scheduled or not?

Notification_service method:

```
  Future<void> scheduleNotifications(String title,var payload,var yy,var mm,var dd,var hh,var ii) async {
    
    final tz.Location   timeZoneName =  tz.getLocation('Africa/Cairo');
    tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName.toString()));
    DateTime current_time=tz.TZDateTime.now(timeZoneName);
    print("loc function is ${tz.local}");

    var schedule_30before=tz.TZDateTime(timeZoneName,yy,mm,dd,hh,ii).subtract(Duration(minutes: 30));
    // TZDateTime(Location location, int year, [int month = 1, int day = 1, int hour = 0, int minute = 0, int second = 0, int millisecond = 0, int microsecond = 0])


    if(current_time.isBefore(schedule_30before)){

      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        0,
        title,
        "The Webinar will start after 30 minutes",
        //tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add( Duration(seconds: 5)),
        schedule_30before,
        // tz.TZDateTime.local(yy,mm,dd,hh,ii,xx),
        NotificationDetails(android: _androidNotificationDetails),
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation: UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
        payload:payload,

      );
    }

  }
```

I run the method in  `initState()` to run it once :

```
_notificationService.scheduleNotifications(title,payload,sp_d_1,sp_d_2,sp_d_3,sp_t_1,sp_t_2);
```

The problem is that when the user open the app every time,it will call this method every time.I need a way to check if the notification is already scheduled,ignore to call it again.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve list of pending notification request

```
final List<PendingNotificationRequest> pendingNotificationRequests =
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.pendingNotificationRequests();
```